# Span a background color to the full width of the page inside a max-width div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the background color of a div span to the full width of the page. The only problem is that the container is inside a max-width div and can't be taken outside.

This is the picture of how it looks at the moment: [image]

I want the light grey background on the breadcrumb block to expand to the full width of the page.

Is it possible to do this without taking it out of the max-width container? I haven't been able to find anything by searching.

This is the container that includes the page and the breadcrumb trail:

```
#container {
    width:90%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width:1300px;
}
.mod_breadcrumb a {
    display: block;
    color: #a45722 !important;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: .8em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.mod_breadcrumb {
    line-height: .2em;
    color: #a45722 !important;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin-top:-4px !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.mod_breadcrumb ul {
        margin-top:5px !important;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @sebastianbrosch edited

Comment: off course  it is possible. But first of all provide your html code.

Comment: Please include your `html` in your question, @Gerardo.

Comment: @Rounin Could I provide a link to the website? It is behind a cms and the code is pretty large.

Comment: You only need to provide the `html` for the horizontal menu-bar.